# Lombok module not found with Java 11 and Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

Currently, I cannot get this project to run, somehow the Gradle cannot find the Lombok module. I'm using

- lombok version 1.18.12
- OpenJDK 11.0.8
- Gradle 6.4

Based on this [github issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1723), then the problem should be solved at this version, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the error

```
> Task :Model-library:compileJava FAILED
/home/dauto98/path..to..project/src/main/java/module-info.java:2: error: module not found: lombok
    requires static lombok;
```

below is my gradle.build.kts file

```
plugins {
    java
    `java-library`
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("junit", "junit", "4.12")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12")

    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

my `module-info.java` file

```
module my.module.main {
    requires static lombok;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found out that the problem is I didn't turn on module path inference explicitly in the Gradle build file as stated in [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_modular)

Add this to the `gradle.build.kts` file:

```
plugins.withType<JavaPlugin>().configureEach {
    configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
        modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
    }
}
```